# Converting list of dictionary to data frame and merging to orginal dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a column in the data frame with a list of dictionary.

```
import requests
url = "https://data.maldita.es/ukrainefacts"
resp=requests.get(url)
data=resp.json()
df=pd.DataFrame.from_records(data)
print(df.shape)
```

I am converting this column to another dataframe like this

```
df1=pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(x) for x in df["ocurrences"]], ignore_index=True)
```

I am merging the df1 with df as

```
df=pd.concat([df,df1],axis=1)
```

The problem is that df1 has more rows than df due to dictionary item, I want to merge the dataframe based on the id, but while expanding the dictionary, I am not able to use the column id.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @PandaKim I have updated the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If initial `df` looks like this:

```
  col1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               ocurrences
1    a  [{'country': {'name': 'Montenegro'}, 'date': '2023-06-15', 'factchecker': 'Raskrinkavanje.me', 'debunkTitle': 'No proof for the claims of Kirilov about bio-weapons in Ukraine', 'debunkLink': 'https://www.raskrinkavanje.me/analiza/nema-dokaza-za-tvrdnje-kirilova-o-bioloskom-oruzju-u-ukrajini/'}]
2    b                                                              [{'country': {'name': 'Poland'}, 'date': '2023-06-16', 'factchecker': 'xxx', 'debunkTitle': 'yyy', 'debunkLink': 'zzz'}, {'country': {'name': 'Finland'}, 'date': '2023-06-17', 'factchecker': 'a', 'debunkTitle': 'b', 'debunkLink': 'c'}]
```

Then you can `.explode` the `ocurrences` column, apply `pd.Series` and then `.concat`:

```py
df = df.explode("ocurrences")

df = pd.concat([df, df["ocurrences"].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
print(df)
```

---

EDIT:

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests

url = "https://data.maldita.es/ukrainefacts"
resp = requests.get(url)
data = resp.json()

df=pd.DataFrame(data).explode('ocurrences')
df = pd.concat([df, df.pop("ocurrences").apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
      index  code         format                                                        source                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              disinfoLink                                                                                                                  featuredImage                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    disinfo     minDate                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           localizedDisinfo                             country        date                      factchecker                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           debunkTitle                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             debunkLink
0      5711    -1           Text                                         Online media/Facebook                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=208133318849911&id=100089597323293  https://anti-maidan.com/2023/06/16/vajno-ydar-raket-po-kievy-ykrainskaia-provokaciia-k-vizity-prezidentov-stran-afriki-video/                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            2023-06-16                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       {'en': '', 'es': ''}                 {'name': 'Ukraine'}  2023-06-16                     Stopfake.org                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         Fake: Kyiv Missile Strikes – Ukraine’s Provocation for African Leaders’ Visit                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 https://www.stopfake.org/en/fake-kyiv-missile-strikes-ukraine-s-provocation-for-african-leaders-visit/
1      5708    -1           Text                                         Facebook/Online media                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        https://lat.sputnikportal.rs/20230526/rusija-sad-na-teritoriji-ukrajine-razvijaju-biolosko-oruzje-1156231187.html                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            2023-06-15                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       {'en': '', 'es': ''}              {'name': 'Montenegro'}  2023-06-15                Raskrinkavanje.me                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       No proof for the claims of Kirilov about bio-weapons in Ukraine                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   https://www.raskrinkavanje.me/analiza/nema-dokaza-za-tvrdnje-kirilova-o-bioloskom-oruzju-u-ukrajini/

...
```

Note: You can use `.groupby('index')` to group the dataframe by column `index` afterwards for example.

Comment: thanks, the initial df is okay, but in the result I get multiple rows for each id, correspoind, country, date, factchecker, can we solve it?

Comment: @Alexandra I'd suggest to edit your question and put there minimal reproducible example (small sample data + expected output, in text form)

Comment: I have updated the code

Comment: @Alexandra I've updated my answer.

Comment: thanks, you are too precise in all your answer, I am new in pandas/python, can you please something which can build the foundation for this.